# How to find the size of your doubly linked list?

Tags: java, function, doubly-linked-list, deque, sentinel

I have a class `SLList` where a doubly linked list `SLList` would be taking in values of any generic type.

I have used sentinels to help myself in working with these, and here is my code so far:

```java
public class SLList<T> {

    private class IntNode {
        private T data;
        private IntNode previous;
        private IntNode next;

        public IntNode(T data, IntNode previous, IntNode next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.previous = previous;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public IntNode() {
            next = previous = this;
        }
    }

    IntNode sentinel;

    public SLList() {
        sentinel = new IntNode();
    }

    public int size() {
        int x = 0;
        while (sentinel.next != null) {
            x++;
        }
        return x;
    }

    public String makestring() {
        return sentinel.data.toString();
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to turn my doubly linked list into a string using `makestring()` but I'm confused on how can I implement this properly into code. Can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Also, if anyone can see if my `size()` function is wrong, please feel free to correct me

Comment: When you create your SLList it already has one element. What do you do with this existing element when you add another element? You have to indicate the method that adds the element.

Comment: so while(sentinel.next != null) {
            x++;
        }
        return x; ?

Comment: since SLList already have one element

Comment: [Edit] your question and post a [mcve]. Create a [doubly-linked] list and then post what string should be returned by method `makestring` for this list.

Comment: Would be more efficient if you keep track of the size each time the list is modified.

Comment: @ChengThao can u elaborate please. I don't know how to do this with sentinels present.

Comment: The title is "find the size of the list" the question body is "how to implement makestring?". Please pick one question and stick with it

Comment: What Cheng Thao means is that you shouldn't calculate the size in `size()` but keep a variable in your list and each time you add a node you increment and each time you remove a node you decrement that variable.

Comment: As for "how to implement `makestring()`?" - think about what exactly you'd like the string to contain. What's its purpose? If you can provide that information you might already see some implementation options as well. And please don't ask "what should I put into the string?" - that's _your_ decision.